# Recalculating Cells

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I have a list with email addresses that were pulled into a an excel sheet. I want the emails to show as mailto links. If you double click into the cell and then hit enter that is what happens. But the list is long and I want to do it for every row. Is there a macro I can use to complete this task for me? Recording didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to use the

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:")
```

function, not sure if you actually want to be able to generate emails and send them or just prefer that format for the cells. [This](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2688-excel-mailto-link.html) site will help you.

Hope this helps and Good luck!!